# Cannot Resolve .STActivity AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I have been trying to develop an app that uses OpenStreetmaps for GPS tracking and I am almost done but for one error in the AndroidManifest.XML file. It says "Cannot Resolve Symbol STActivity". I do not remember encountering this problem before. Here's the segment of the code causing the problem

```
<activity android:label="Centripetal GPS Tracker" android:name=".STActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sai.

Comment: Do you actually have a class `STActivity` in the same package as declared in your manifest root element?

Answer (score 0):

there's not much room for errors in the manifest.

first make sure that .STActivity does indeed exist in your code,
make that it is the correct path!
meaning, if your activity is in a different package called UI for example,
then you should fill it in : " UI.STActivity ".

can't give any more tips or advices on that error since you didn't post any more details for me to work with.

hope I helped a little bit :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was indeed in UI. Much appreciated :)

Comment: glad it helped :) if your answer is resolved please mark my answer as correct so the question will be closed.